# that = this vs underscore's bind vs standard ES bind - memory usage

Tags: javascript, bind, underscore.js

Which one will take up less memory?

1. that=this pattern
2. underscore's bind method
3. standard ES bind

This is not a question about which one is 'better'.

I would like to understand which method takes up less memory and why.

Comment: It won't make a difference really. Native `.bind` might use less memory, because it's, well, native, but that also depends on the implementation.

Comment: This feels like a micro-optimization.

Comment: Might it not depend on how you're using each of the options? Will there be multiple functions that could all use the same `that`, for example?

Comment: A test with profiling would probably bring some results but personally I wouldn't bet on these results being consistent between browsers, context and in the future.

Comment: I think it's a reasonable question.  It just happens that because it concerns a language with many widely-used implementations, there's no good answer.